# Calling an excel file via a macro

Tags: vba

I want to create a macro that pulls a file by allowing the user to browse and locate the file from his/her local and then perform some functions on the pulled file.

I am not sure how to incorporate the browsing file feature in the macro.

Comment: will the target file always be an Excel workbook?

Comment: Sounds like you want to use [`Application.FileDialog`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/VBA/Excel-VBA/articles/application-filedialog-property-excel)

Comment: yes ... but it wont be a "xlsm" type it will be an "xlsx" extension

Answer (score 0):

Use `Application.FileDialog`, there are lot's of examples in SO and elsewhere on the internet, for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21723223/open-a-workbook-using-filedialog-and-manipulate-it)

Answer (score 0):

The below will open and set wkbFileToOpen, you will then be able to use this as your workbook to manipulate.

```
Dim vFileToOpen As Variant
Dim wkbFileToOpen As Workbook

'Ask the user to select the file, you can change your desired file extensions and file types
vFileToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename("Excel Files (*.xls),*.xls,", 1, "Select the workbook", , False)

'if the user cancels, then vFileToOpen will be false, so we need to check there's a value
If Not vFileToOpen Then

    Workbooks.Open vFileToOpen
    Set wkbFileToOpen = ActiveWorkbook

End If
```